# How can I copy text from the description on a Trello card?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

When I click on the description text of a Trello card that I have permission to edit, I'm immediately taken to an edit view. This is annoying if I actually need to copy some text from the description - perhaps a command that needs to be run - but makes copying code blocks almost impossible: in the edit view (Markdown syntax), all code is preceded by spaces or tabs, so I can't just paste it into a text editor.

How do I stop Trello going into edit mode when I click on the description text, and only do that when clicking on the "Edit the card description" link?

Comment: You can have code in Trello without the spaces/tabs before each line - use [triple backticks](http://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello) on their own lines before & after the code block: \`\`\`

Answer (score 3):

In the description, at the place where you want to start copying, press the left mouse button *and immediately start moving* towards the end of the text you want to select. Then release the mouse button. After that, press Ctrl-C to copy the text selected to the clipboard.

(In the title, the card immediately goes into edit-title-mode when you release the mouse button while still in the title text. In that case, you must move towards outside the area of the card title to prevent this behavior.)

Comment: Just tried this in Firefox, and as soon as I stop selecting, it goes into edit mode and highlights the whole description.

Comment: @IainHallam, indeed. My description was for Google Chrome. In Firefox, you need the same trick for the description as I described for the title: continue to select the text beyond the end of the field. Then edit mode apparently isn't enabled.